# How to find three column values at different levels using TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table as under

[image]

The expected output should be

[image]

*That is the latest information for that Account should be picked.*

**table schema**

```
declare @t table (transactionDate Date ,AccountId int, Address varchar(50) Null,Mobile varchar(50) null,Email varchar(50) null)
insert into @t 
select '01/31/2018', 1,null,'',null union all
select '01/30/2018',1,null,null,'user1@testmail.com' union all
select '01/29/2018',1,null,null,null union all
select '01/28/2018',1,null,null,'user12@xyz.com' union all
select '01/26/2018',1,'Address1',null,null union all
select '01/17/2018',2,'Address2',null,null union all
select '01/15/2018',2,null,null,null union all
select '01/14/2018',2,null,null,null union all
select '01/12/2018',2,null,null,null union all
select '01/11/2018',2,null,'345678',null union all
select '01/10/2018',2,null,null,null union all
select '01/04/2018',2,null,'67891','user2@test.com' union all
select '01/03/2018',2,null,null,null union all
select '01/01/2018',2,'Adress222',null,null union all
select '01/30/2018',3,null,null,null union all
select '01/30/2018',4,'Addrss4','1234','user4@test.com' union all
select '01/30/2018',5,'Addrss5',null,'user5@test.com' union all
select '01/30/2018',5,null,'3456789',null

declare @loanAccounts table(AccountId int)
insert into @loanAccounts select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
```

**My attempt so far**

```
;with addressCTE as(
-- for Address
Select transactionDate,AccountId,Address
from
(select Rn=ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by AccountId Order by transactionDate desc)
,transactionDate,AccountId,Address
from @t
where len(Address) > 0)x where x.Rn=1)

,mobileCTE as(
-- for Mobile
Select transactionDate,AccountId,Mobile
from
(select Rn=ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by AccountId Order by transactionDate desc)
,transactionDate,AccountId,Mobile
from @t
where len(Mobile) > 0)x where x.Rn=1)

,emailCTE as(
-- for email
Select transactionDate,AccountId,Email
from
(select Rn=ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by AccountId Order by transactionDate desc)
,transactionDate,AccountId,Email
from @t
where len(Email) > 0)x where x.Rn=1)

select la.AccountId, a.transactionDate,a.Address
from @loanAccounts la 
    left outer join addressCTE a on la.AccountId = a.AccountId
```

I am lost after that.

Comment: why not use `ISNULL(columnName, '')`?

Comment: It looks like you are just removing the records which only have `NULL` values.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
select
    transactionDate, AccountId, isnull(iif(transactionDate = maxAddress, Address, ''), '')
    , isnull(iif(transactionDate = maxMobile, Mobile, ''), '')
    , isnull(iif(transactionDate = maxEmail, Email, ''), '')
from (
    select 
        *
        , maxAddress = max(iif(isnull(len(Address), 0) > 0, transactionDate, null)) over (partition by AccountId)
        , maxMobile = max(iif(isnull(len(Mobile), 0) > 0, transactionDate, null)) over (partition by AccountId)
        , maxEmail = max(iif(isnull(len(Email), 0) > 0, transactionDate, null)) over (partition by AccountId)
        , maxDate = max(transactionDate) over (partition by AccountId)
    from 
        @t
) t
where
    transactionDate in (maxAddress, maxMobile, maxEmail, case when maxAddress is null and maxMobile is null and maxEmail is null then maxDate end)
```

Comment: we are close but for a) Account id =2, for 2018-01-04, the phone won't appear since the latest has come on 2018-01-11 (b) Record for Account Id = 3 is missing...

Comment: 1 small prob though.. for 2018-01-31, account # 1, that row should not appear

Comment: Updated. Now everything should be ok

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for,

```
SELECT transactionDate,AccountId,ISNULL(Address,'') Address,ISNULL(Mobile,'') Mobile,
       ISNULL(Email,'') Email 
FROM @t
GROUP BY transactionDate,AccountId,Address,Mobile,Email
HAVING  (Address is not null AND Address <> '') 
        OR (Mobile is not null AND Mobile <> '') 
        OR (Email is not null AND Email <> '')
ORDER BY AccountId
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HAO7853)